# why python3 asks for urllib2? when already imported urllib.request & urllib.error?

Tags: python-3.x

`I tried to solve this issue in so many ways, but always I get the same error.
if someone can tell me the solution to this error I will be very grateful.
Here is the is code which I am currently using.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
!pip install lasio
import lasio 
#Data links
well_path = well ="https://bit.1y/wireline-data"
trajectory_path ="https://bit.1y/trajectory-data"
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from urllib.request import urlopen
well= lasio.read(well_path)
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lasio\reader.py in open_file(file_ref, **encoding_kwargs)
95             try:
---> 96                 import urllib2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

Comment: It looks like you've got a version of `lasio` installed that was written for Python 2, not Python 3, and you're running on Python 3. Did you perhaps mean to run `pip3 install lasio`? It shouldn't have installed a Python 2 version for Py3 in any event, but that's clearly what happened (`urllib2` is a Python 2-only built-in).

Comment: i really dont understand where is the problem , i did as you say and i even re-install the hole anaconda system and then used pip3 , but nothing changes .

Comment: Wait, I just realized you're mixing `pip` with ananconda. Is there some reason you're not installing things with `conda`? I'm worried you've got some nasty mixed up system going on here.